# How to add c++ to visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I`ve downloaded visual studio 2019 recently and there was an option to preload python,c++ and etc. I preloaded only python. How to add c++?

Comment: Visual Studio Installer is a separate program that should have been installed.  That is responsible for modifying Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the start menu and launch "Visual Studio Installer" and click the Modify button. You can add C++ from the next steps.

[image]